# Windows Features?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We actually have a [windows-features](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-features) tag (with 29 questions).  I would just nuke it, but there are 29 questions.  Any conceivable reason not to?

Comment: It's a meta tag. Nuke it.

Comment: What was the tag being for?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro, some related to the "Windows Features" configuration screen.  Some were just generally about features of Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deed is done.  And now the answer meets the 30 character minimum.